# Polynomial++: How to increment p(x) by 1

Tags: c++, class, vector, polynomial-math

I have a `Polynomial` class, and I am trying to define `operator++`, both pre- and post- incrementation, as well as trying to define the pre- and post- decrementation, namely `operator--`. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class Polynomial
{
public:
    Polynomial();
    Polynomial(vector<int>coeffs);
    /*
    .
    .
    .
    */
    Polynomial operator++();
    Polynomial& operator++ (int unused);
    Polynomial operator--();
    Polynomial& operator-- (int unused);
    /*
    .
    .
    .
    */

private:
    vector<int> coefficient;
};

Polynomial Polynomial::operator++()
{
    coefficient[0]++;
    return *this;
}
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator++ (int unused)
{
    Polynomial copy(*this);
    coefficient[0]++;
    return copy;
}
Polynomial Polynomial::operator--()
{
    coefficient[0]--;
    return *this;
}
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator-- (int unused)
{
    Polynomial copy(*this);
    coefficient[0]--;
    return copy;
}
```

I get an error when trying to do something like this in main:

`Polynomial p(`...some vector...`);`

`cout << p++;`

Comment: Usually, pre-increment would return a reference. Post-increment should return a value. You seem to have it the wrong way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning references to temporaries from your postfix operators:

```
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator++ (int unused)
{
    Polynomial copy(*this);
    coefficient[0]++;
    return copy;     // returning reference to local variable
}
```

This is undefined behaviour. You have the return type of post and pre-increment the wrong way around. You need something like this:

```
Polynomial& operator++();
Polynomial operator++ (int);
Polynomial& operator--();
Polynomial operator-- (int);
```